# Cursor is off the sorted item of jquery-ui-draggable when its parent is hidden out of screen during sort

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable, jquery-ui-sortable

[Demo](http://codepen.io/stonecold1111/pen/VLbVZM)

In the demo, the sortable items are in container `.area` which has a fixed position. When items being sorted and dragged into another container, I want `.area` to move out of the screen by using `transform: translate(0,0)`.

But the problem is that the sorted item is way off the cursor during sort. I have tried `cusorAt` but it doesn't seem to be the solution. I guess the item needs a recalculation of its relative position since its parent `.area` has its position changed. How can I sort the problem? Any help would be appreciated.

```
$(".j_drag").sortable({
    connectWith: ".connectedSortable",
    items:"img",
    start: function( event, ui ) {
        $('.area').removeClass('open');
    },
    stop: function(){
        $('.area').addClass('open');
    },
    cursorAt: { right: 0 }
})
```

CSS

```
.connectedSortable{margin:auto;background:beige;height:150px;width:150px}

img{display:block;}

.area{  position: fixed;
  z-index: 999;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 35%;
  background: grey;
  -moz-transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
  transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transform: translate(100%, 0);
  -o-transform: translate(100%, 0);
  -webkit-transform: translate(100%, 0);
  transform: translate(100%, 0);
  -ms-transform: translate(100%, 0);}

.open{  -moz-transform: translate(0,0);
  -o-transform: translate(0,0);
  -webkit-transform: translate(0,0);
  -ms-transform: translate(0, 0);
  transform: translate(0, 0);}
```

HTML

```
<h3>Items</h3>
   <div class="area open">
       <div class="j_drag"><img src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/a610b9cd94825418d77db14b71395bcc?s=48&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1"/>
        <img src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/a610b9cd94825418d77db14b71395bcc?s=48&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1"/>
       <img src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/a610b9cd94825418d77db14b71395bcc?s=48&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1"/>
        <img src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/a610b9cd94825418d77db14b71395bcc?s=48&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1"/>
       </div></div>
<div class='j_drag connectedSortable'></div>
```

Comment: Please see ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), where the consensus is "no, they should not"!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to solve this would be to remove the `sortable` elements from `area` and place them in `body` on `start` event and use `refreshPositions` so the drag position is correctly calculated. Like this:

```
 start: function( event, ui ) {
    ui.helper.appendTo('body')
    $('.j_drag').sortable('refreshPositions')
    $('.area').removeClass('open');
 },
```

The revert will be a little weird, but there's probably a way to make it look a bit better. Already by adding revert option it looks better.

See codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/QbvJEX